# How to add JNI (C/C++ native code) to existing Android Studio project

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Like the title says - how to add native code to existing Android Studio project, without breaking the current project, including gradle and proguard settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow this steps from your existing project:

### 1. Modify build.gradle (Module app) to look like this (a lot changes!):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

    model {
        android.signingConfigs {
            create ("myConfig") {
                keyAlias '--your-key-alias--'
                keyPassword '--key-password--'
                storeFile file('--/path/to/keystore.jks--')
                storePassword '--store-password--'
            }
        }
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 25
            buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "--your.app.name--"
                minSdkVersion.apiLevel 19
                targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 25
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android-optimize.txt'))
                    proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
                    signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.myConfig")
                }
            }
            ndk {
                moduleName "--c-file--"
                ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
            }

        }
        android.dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2048m"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    }
```

You can copy/paste the above code and modify at least the values with "--value--" to match yours.

### 2. Modify build.gradle (Project)

where it says something like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

to this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3'
}
```

The number in my example **0.9.3** is the latest version of gradle-experimental to be found [here](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/). Eventually change your gradle version in  *gradle-wrapper.properties* to the version recommended by Android Studio if you did not already.

### 3. Move your proguard settings file

`proguard-android-optimize.txt` to `app/proguard-android-optimize.txt`

### 4. Add the call from java

like this

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("--c-file--");
}
private native byte my_jni(Context context, byte[] mByte, int i);
```

changing to your needs. The example above loads the c-file (write it without the extension) - the same one declared in the gradle file, and calls the function my_jni, passing the application's Context, some byte array and some int, expecting that the functions returns a byte.

### 5. Create the function in JNI:

Now the name of your function is highlighted in red - allow Android Studio to create it `Create function ...` with clicking on the red lamp on the row. This creates the function in your c file and changes focus to it.

### Done

Further reading [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0).

Tips:

- Take care to `free` everything you `malloc`, `ReleaseByteArrayElements` for every `GetByteArrayElements` and so on
- Take care how to properly return some *dangerous* values from C to Java, like arrays and Strings

Comment: Don't do this as experimental gradle is deprecated and no longer maintained, migrade to cmake asap

Comment: i have .so file of other app that i have decompile i don't have native-lib.cpp file of that .so means i don't have native code i only have .so can i integrate and run it in my project because when i m runing the project this error is coming java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.krunal.camarademo.Libs.nativesystem.DMDHDR.getBracketedCount() (tried Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount and Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount__)

Answer (score 76):

Since Android Studio 3.1 its possible easy way:

**1. Create `cpp` folder inside `app\src\main`.**

**2. Create `<YOUR_FILE_NAME>.cpp` file in `app\src\main\cpp` path (e.g. native-lib.cpp)**

**3. Add `CMakeLists.txt` file to `app` folder.**

In that file name of the library, `.cpp` file path and some other settings should be defined, e.g. (from new, empty Android Studio Project with C++ support):

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          YOUR_CPP_FILE_NAME

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

**4. Add to build.gradle (Module app) `externalNativeBuild` tag with reference to `CMakeLists.txt` into `android` section:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    externalNativeBuild {               <--- these lines should be added
        cmake {                         <--- these lines should be added
            path "CMakeLists.txt"       <--- these lines should be added
        }                               <--- these lines should be added
    }                                   <--- these lines should be added
}
```

**5. Add to build.gradle (Module app) `externalNativeBuild` tag with `cmake` tag into `defaultConfig` section:**

```
...
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "<YOUR_APP_ID>"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    externalNativeBuild {   <--- these lines should be added
        cmake {             <--- these lines should be added
            cppFlags ""     <--- these lines should be added
        }                   <--- these lines should be added
    }                       <--- these lines should be added
}
...
```

(example of "basic" `build.gradle` file also available in new, empty Android Studio project with C++ support)

**6. Resync Project with Gradle files**

By clicking Sync Project [image: Sync Project button on Toolbar] in the toolbar. NB! In Android Studio 3.3, the icon is [image: Android Studio 3.3 Sync Project button on Toolbar].

Also, take a look at [Official Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code).

**PS. If files not shown in `cpp` folder:**

try `File/Invalidate Caches & Restart` as [Thinh Vu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5570467/thinh-vu) mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Since last update of Android Studio (3.3.1) my cpp folder is empty. Was there any update on how to integrate native source files or is it a bug in AS?

Comment: @clash Just create necessary files manually as described in answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. I always had my files visible in the cpp folder in AS, but now they are gone. I just readded everything as described, invalidated caches and reimported gradle project, but without success. I guess it's either a bug or a change in the workflow.

Comment: @clash 1) you can add them via file manager; 2) you should configure `CMakeList.txt` properly.

Comment: I followed your steps above (it's the same steps described in Google NDK tutorial) but all cpp files in this folder still hidden (like clash's case).

I also added <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" /> into .iml file but it doesn't work.

But the build is still success so I just ignore this issue (eventhough it hurt my feeling a little bit)

IMO, it's a very stupid IDE when comparing with Visual Studio.

Comment: @ThinhVu Please double check path and file names of your files and it description in `CMakeLists.txt` (if you have several files - all of them should be described in `add_library()` of `CMakeLists.txt`, if your files organized via subfolders you should use  `add_subdirectory()` in "main" `CMakeLists.txt` and describe subfolders structures on its `CMakeLists.txt` files  etc.).

Comment: @clash Oh I just tried again by adding <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" /> into app.iml file then File/Save -> File/Invalidate Caches & Restart (more than 10 times I guessed - sometimes it works, sometimes not) and now the files shown in cpp folder.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko All my configuration are correct.
The problem come from Android Studio cache I think.

Comment: @ThinhVu May be. In all my cases, it was enough to synchronize the project with Gradle files (p. 6).

Comment: @ThinhVu Your recommendation added to the answer.

Comment: I have android studio 3.6 in ubuntu 18.04 and your howto steps worked. The existing android project already have C++ codes but I don't see them and I cannot trace into them. All JNI calls work, and project rebuilds also rebuilds the so library. But I cannot step debug trace into these C++. I followed your steps, and I created a new C++ file and I am able to step debug from JNI to this new C++ file. I still cannot do it to the existing C++ code base, but at least I'm getting somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the useful and step by step procedure.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy way now, just right-click on your module in Project explorer and click on Add C++ to the Module:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

To see the structure of a code with JNI, create an empty project with C++. File=>New=>New project=>Native C++.