Android studio doesn't debug native C code
I sometimes get SIGSEGV and sometimes SIGTRAP or SIGBUS in logcat without any stacktrace
2024-08-07 12:57:59.218 28298-29247 TEST                    com.ammar.filescenter                D  Native code called
2024-08-07 12:58:00.828 28298-28298 libc                    com.ammar.filescenter                A  Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 0x40090854000061 in tid 28298 (mar.filescenter), pid 28298 (mar.filescenter)
2024-08-07 12:58:01.147 29349-29349 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Process name is com.ammar.filescenter, not key_process
2024-08-07 12:58:01.147 29349-29349 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Cmdline: com.ammar.filescenter
2024-08-07 12:58:01.147 29349-29349 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  pid: 28298, tid: 28298, name: mar.filescenter  >>> com.ammar.filescenter <<<
2024-08-07 12:58:11.590 28777-29478 TEST                    com.ammar.filescenter                D  Native code called
2024-08-07 12:58:12.955 28777-29548 TEST                    com.ammar.filescenter                D  Native code called
2024-08-07 12:58:13.922 28777-29569 TEST                    com.ammar.filescenter                D  Native code called
2024-08-07 12:58:14.522 28777-29574 TEST                    com.ammar.filescenter                D  Native code called
2024-08-07 12:58:15.038 28777-29579 TEST                    com.ammar.filescenter                D  Native code called
2024-08-07 12:58:15.100 28777-29384 libc                    com.ammar.filescenter                A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 29384 (binder:28777_2), pid 28777 (mar.filescenter)
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (29585) for package com.ammar.filescenter ----------------------------
2024-08-07 12:58:15.398 29582-29582 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Process name is com.ammar.filescenter, not key_process
2024-08-07 12:58:15.398 29582-29582 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Cmdline: com.ammar.filescenter
2024-08-07 12:58:15.398 29582-29582 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  pid: 28777, tid: 29384, name: binder:28777_2  >>> com.ammar.filescenter <<<


BTW I call the native function from a java thread so Idk what is that RenderThread thing in the logcat
I tried to set breakpoints in the native code but android studio doesn't stop at these breakpoints I click on the bug symbol to run code 
but android studio doesn't stop at these points I tried to set a breakpoint it at a print statement in native code it did print but execution didn't stop.
You can see from logcat that it did print

I have no idea what to do or how to take the error down
btw android studio doesn't recognize C files so this might be related to the problem

I use CMake and Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1

Please don't post log output (e.g. logcat) as screenshot. Just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code. The log text the color is irrelevant. Make sure the path in your project is app/src/main/cpp see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45118175/150978
